# I think my cat broke it's leg

Tags: cats, injury

My cat got its leg trapped in a door and his leg is swollen. It's the leg on th upper part of the picture. When it first happened he could put a little bit of pressure on it but now its swollen and won't put any pressure on it. I have given him some food and he can walk but he limps. He doesn't seem to be in pain but when I touch his leg he screams. For this reason I have not felt the leg to see if it's broken. He also has a small cut on the side of his leg where he trapped it in the door. I was wondering if anyone could tell me if it's broken and tell me what to do other than take him to the vet tomorrow.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Take him to the vet tonight!

If there is absolutely no potential for an emergency vet.  Do your best to keep him inactive, until you can reach the vet first thing tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thankyou so much ive been so woried about him but do you think he has broken his leg? it dosnt matter if you dont know because i will take him to the vets anyway tomorrow.

Comment: No way to tell from photo unless the bone is sticking out or there's an abnormal bend.

Comment: +1 If you had a broken leg, or at least an injury so severe that you screamed when someone touched it, would you wait until tomorrow to see a doctor? You can call most vets even when they are closed, and the answering service can usually refer you to a vet "on call" to handle emergencies.